# SQL server schema to accomodate duplicate PK/FK values from autonomous Access data bases

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, duplication

I have several test stations with Access databases that have identical structures (12 related tables each).  They are independent and all internal PK & FK values (Autonumber PK & Long Integer FK) can duplicate from station to station. The first table in each station has Part Number, Serial Number & Time Stamp fields that, across all stations, will be unique.  (no one unit PN/SN can be on two stations at the same time).
The goal is to push all the test data from all the test stations to a SQL Server database.  The original PK & FK values do not have to be retained. I am familiar with Access and a total newbe with SQL Server.  I have tried to get this working using SSMA & SSMS.  I have migrated a single Access sample with partial success.  The SQL PK values will increment correctly but the FK values are either NULL or if not allowed, '0'.  I would expect there is a standard approach to this issue but to date, I haven't found it.

mendosi, Here is where my ignorance jumps to the top.  How do I publish the SQL table definitions?

peter,  I checked the 'Link Tables' box and my Access front end is connected.  I have several combo boxes that select query criteria that, ultimately, will need pass through queries and / or stored procedures to populate their lists.  But until I get passed the PK / FK issue those will have to wait.

Comment: If it's not too late (i.e. if you haven't solved this already), would you post the definitions of your parent table and a child table as SSMA has created them in SQL Server.

Comment: Have you considered having the data in SQL and just attaching access as a front end? Let SQL manage the primary keys with identity columns. Google access linked tables.